# check if [variable name] + [number] exists?

Tags: javascript

I'm using the code below to check if var1 exists, then assigning another variable (promt) to store var1 provided that the user types in the variable. Problem is I have about twenty variables I need to check so my code looks like the below times ten:

```
    if (typeof var1 !== 'undefined') {
        if(selection==var1){
            var promt = var1;
        }           
    }
    if (typeof var2 !== 'undefined') {
        if(selection==var2){
            var promt = var2;
        }           
    }
```

This (a) makes a ton of inefficient code and (b) may cause errors if I have over twenty variables. 
 Is there a way to check if var1, var2, var3, etc.. exists then stop checking when the variables stop?
The goal is to be able to have one hundred variables and still have the same amount of code I would have if there were two.

Comment: Use an array...

Comment: Use regular expression

Comment: To add, you could probably loop through that array and check for truthiness, then assign accordingly

Comment: Why would you want to create that many *unreadable* variables (`var1` doesn't indicate anything about what that variable stores or is used for)?

Comment: The whole thing is based completely off of user input, so I do not know what the variables will be storing

Comment: @JasonCastillo then, seriously, why not just use an array?

Comment: The point of this is to be able to create more variables automatically, so I don't know how many I need.

Comment: You can for example use a loop and get the variable using window['var'+i], but I am 99% sure there is no need to use that unreadable bad code, you can use an array as others are saying, and add as many elements as you need into the array.

Comment: @JasonCastillo So why not use an array?

Comment: @JasonCastillo `var userInput = [];` makes an array and you can use an unlimited number of `userInput.push(newInput);`. I can guarantee you it will handle variable amount of inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your variables are fields on an object you can easily build the field names dynamically:

```
fieldname = 'var' + index;
if (typeof obj[fieldname] !== 'undefined') {
    if (selection == obj[fieldname]){
        var promt = obj[fieldname];
    }           
}
```

For local variables I however can't provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first `var` is **reserved word** in javascript, so you cannot use it as variable names, hence I use `_var` here instead.

I made a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ckmichael8/b9o6jt5w/) for this solution, so check it out pls.

You may also look at the code below:

```
for (i in _var) {
  // Loop through all values in var
  if ((typeof _var [i] !== undefined) &&
    selection_array.indexOf(_var [i]) >= 0) {
    // note that array.indexOf returns -1 if selection_array does not contain var [i]
        prompt = _var[i]; // use this if you only want last var[i] satisifying the condition to be stored
    prompt_array.push(_var[i]);// use this if you want to store all satisifying values of var[i]
  }
}
```

Also check the below snippet

```js
// Lets declare and give some example value to _var, Note that you cannot use var as variable name as it is a reserver word in javascript
var _var = ['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3', 'foo4'];

// Declare a variable called prompt (actually not necessary normally)
var prompt;

// Declare a array called prompt_array to store the output
var prompt_array = [];

// Declare and give some example value to selection_array
var selection_array = ['foo2', 'foo3'];

// main program to solve the problem
for (i in _var) {
  // Loop through all values in var
  if ((typeof _var [i] !== undefined) &&
    selection_array.indexOf(_var [i]) >= 0) {
    // note that array.indexOf returns -1 if selection_array does not contain var [i]
  prompt = _var[i]; // use this if you only want last var[i] satisifying the condition to be stored
    prompt_array.push(_var[i]);// use this if you want to store all satisifying values of var[i]
  }
}

// output for visualizing the result
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += 'prompt = ' + prompt + '<br/>';
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += 'prompt_array = ' + prompt_array.toString();
```

```html
<div id="output">

</div>
```

You can ask me through commenting if you have a further problem on this :D.